# Unittesting in Python, How do I check for custom error Message

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am trying to right a test case which passes if an error is raised. Though the class raises custom error.

Below is the error as raised in the original class.

```
else:
            raise MultipleObjectsReturned("Multiple videos met this criteria.")
```

Now When I try to catch it, it return error.

```
def test_get(self):

        with self.assertRaises('MultipleObjectsReturned'):
            self.yt.get()
```

Error:

```
 File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\case.py", line 117, in __exit__
    if not issubclass(exc_type, self.expected):
TypeError: issubclass() arg 2 must be a class or tuple of classes
```

How can I make it catch custom error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First look in your modules their should be somewhere the MultipleObjectsReturned exception defined. Try to look for something like below. It's only an exception since it inherits from class Exception.

```
class MultipleObjectsReturned(Exception):
```

Now you need to inherit this particular exception for your module to be aware of it.

```
from somewhere import MultipleObjectsReturned
```

Once you successfully import you can raise for it since it's an custom exception but don't use it as a string since it's a class.

```
def test_get(self):
        with self.assertRaises(MultipleObjectsReturned):
            self.yt.get()
```

Notice the quotes removed.